# Why is Pi 4 omitted from the quoted list of Raspberrys on which Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 will run?

Tags: raspberrypi, 21.04

Ubuntu 21.04 was released today so perhaps what I describe below is just a website error ?

The page:
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Lists the pies on which Ubuntu Server will run:

- Raspberry Pi 2
- Raspberry Pi 3
- Raspberry Pi 4
- Raspberry Pi 400
- Raspberry Pi CM4

It also lists the pies on which Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 will run:

- Raspberry Pi 400
- Raspberry Pi CM4

My first thought was, if the desktop runs OK on a Pi400 it will run OK on a Pi4 so I should simply download it and take it for a spin.

My second thought was perhaps there is a good reason why the Pi4 is not listed.

What do you think, website error or Ubuntu issue ?

Comment: Performance possibly didn't meet a standard..  I QA-tested Ubuntu Desktop *hirsute* (21.04) on a `hp dc7700 (c2d-e6320, 5gb, nvidia quadro nvs 290)` and sure it installed perfectly, and did run... but the performance isn't quite what I'd like, and my choice would be running a different (*lighter*) desktop on that choice.  I passed the QA-test yes (the test I've in mind is an install test), but it would depend on what you considered 'run'..  The term *walk* maybe more appropriate to GNOME & Ubuntu Desktop on that box.  I don't test pi's thus can only speculated there.

Comment: If a CM4 has more go than a Pi4 then guiverc's idea sounds like a distinct possibility. Is that the case ?

Comment: It looks like the Pi4, CM4 and Pi400 all have the same CPU. The Pi4 and the CM4 are both clocked at 1.5 GHz, the Pi400 is a bit faster at 1.8 GHz. Thus if the the CM4 is no faster than the Pi4 I can't see how guiverc's suggestion holds up.

Comment: I had Ubuntu 20.10 on a Pi 4. I just upgraded to 21.04

Comment: I also upgraded a Pi4 from 20.10 to 21.04, it didn't go well. Both problem and solution are described in this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333713/no-input-from-logitech-k400-after-upgrade-raps-4-to-ubuntu-21-04

The problem could be unique to people using a Logitech wireless keyboard. 
The cause is related Wayland.
A simple solution is to select Xorg instead of Wayland.

Going back to the original question, why is the Pi4 missing from the list of supported pies, website error or Ubuntu issue ?

Both are still possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's sloved at ubuntu answers/launchpad:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/696758