# Keyboard not properly functioning after installing 21.04

Tags: keyboard, raspberrypi, 21.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my Pi4, the installation works fine and until a point the keyboard works fine then suddenly stops working in applications. During and immediately after the installation the keyboard works, a few minutes after the install is completed, the system stops accepting keyboard inputs into applications.

To be very specific, I can log into the machine and able to enter a password. Once logged in, I can click on "Show Applications" and type into the search bar e.g. terminal. However;

Once the application is loaded, the application won't accept any keyboard input. I am able to toggle to <kbd>F3</kbd> and log in via the terminal without any issues.

I have tried the various recommended approaches including:

```
sudo apt remove fwupd   (made not difference)
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all  (was already installed)
```

as well as `mv ~/.config/dconf/user` to something else (didn't seem to make any difference)

None of these work.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: has an image even been released yet for the Pi4?

Comment: I think the answer to that is no it hasn't for the Desktop edition. The omission of Pi4 from the list of supported pies is discussed in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333277/why-is-pi-4-omitted-from-the-quoted-list-of-raspberrys-on-which-ubuntu-desktop-2

Comment: I also decided to give 21.04 Desktop a try on the Pi4 and I have the exact same keyboard issue. My keyboard is a Logitech K400+ wireless keyboard

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the Logitech wireless keyboard, I can confirm the solution in post #1333713 of starting the session as Xorg instead of Wayland works.

Wayland is obviously still not 100% mature...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a solution, but I have the same issues with my Logitech keyboard and mouse combo.

The mouse works just fine.

I can type with my keyboard at the login screen to put in my password, but once the desktop loads it stops working.

Using a Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB model.

Comment: Is anybody able to confirm if this 21.04 keyboard problem is directly related to the use of a Logitech wireless keyboard ? Does replacing the keyboard cure the issue ?

Comment: I also confront this issue. My keyboard is also Logitech. please help

Answer (score 1):

I deployed Ubuntu Mate (20.04 LTS) instead and that ended the problem. I will try the Xorg solution and report back.

Thanks a stack for the input!

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu 21.04 login screen has a button which allows you to switch from Wayland to Xorg (and vice versa).

Select Xorg, it remembers this for next time and it solves the Logitech keyboard problem.

Having done this I now find 21.04 to be an immense improvement over 20.10 on the Pi. On 20.10 I had problems with the sound dropping out every few minutes, the syslog file showed the pi constantly chasing its own tail, busy doing nothing. I am very happy with 21.04 using Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

RPi 4 8GB model, using a Logitech K400+ - seems to have the same issue.
Same RPi using Logitech K850 - seems to have the same issue.

Grabbed the TV Keyboard remote (RT-MWK01 - no idea of the make) and it's fine.

So this looks to be an issue with the Logitech Unifying receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but this fix it:

[Raspberry Forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=310293#p1889485)