# No input from Logitech K400+ after upgrade Raps 4 to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: keyboard, raspberrypi, logitech, 21.04

after upgrading my Raspberry 4 from Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 to 21.04 (64bit) my Logitech Keyboard K400+ doesn't work in all circumstances. After reboot I'm able to type my password, but after that I'm not able to type any character. In Terminal the cursor is not filled and I'm also not able to type anything in URL field of browsers or any text in Libre Office. The only thing the input works are popup windows e.g. for password in software update. Touchpad works fiel (little slow). When plugging in an old USB-cable keyboard not only the usb-cable keyboard work, but the Logitech K400+ suddenly as well.

The system seems to be aware of the Logitech receiver

➜  ~ lsusb | grep Logitech

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Any idea what might help?

Thanks Caunus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use xorg from the gear menu at the login screen. Select your user name the gear menu is in the bottom right corner.

It's an issue with wayland which is now the default display server. Hopefully the issue will be solved soon.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I can confirm that this is still an issue which has not been fixed in Sep 2021. The solution works for me :)  Btw, why Ubuntu set Wayland over Xorg? What's good about it?